# Como obter as postagens de uma página no facebook (não adimistrada por mim) usando a graph-api?

Tags: facebook, api

Preciso coletar as postagens de páginas no Facebook não administradas por mim. Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como fazer isso? É possível utilizando a Graph API Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é possível, mas seu aplicativo ou site vai precisar [obter uma credencial](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) (token) para o usuário poder fazer a consulta.

> ## [`/{page-id}/feed`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/page/feed)
>
> The feed of posts (including status updates) and links published by this page, or by others on this page. There are other edges which provide more specific sets of posts:
>
> - /{page-id}/posts shows only the posts that were published by this page.
> - /{page-id}/tagged shows all public posts in which the page has been tagged.
> - /{page-id}/promotable_posts shows only the posts that can be boosted (includes unpublished and scheduled posts).

É possível testar as consultas no [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), neste caso o Explorer gera um token que é válido por um tempo limitado. Até pode usar esse token no seu app/site mas tem que renovar constantemente.

[image: buscando posts de uma página]

Na documentação pode ver exemplos de como implementar em diferentes linguagens/plataformas:

> [image: documentação JavaScript SDK]